# Test for newline

Tags: c++, newline

I need help testing for a newline. In my program I have

```
char s[9][9];
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
  for(unsigned int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
  {
      cin >> s[i][j];
      if(s[i][j] == '\n')
      {
        cout << "ERROR" << endl;
      }
  }
}
```

How can I get it so that the 2-d char array can detect if there is a newline? My program seems simply to skip the if statement. I would prefer not to use getline or anything either if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use either [`noskipws`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/noskipws/) flag

```
cin >> noskipws >> s[i][j];
```

or [`cin.get ();`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/) method :

```
s[i][j] = cin.get ();
```

Comment: oo thanks! what if i wanted to say what if s[i][j] was > 81 characters? how would i print out the 82nd character?

Comment: @user1567909 your loops iterate 9x9 times. AFAIK: 9x9 == 81 ;) You cannot reach 82 element.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick.

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    char s[9][9];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
      for(unsigned int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
      {
        cin >> noskipws >>s[i][j];
        count++;
          if(s[i][j] == '\n' || count == 82)
          {
            cout << "ERROR" << endl;
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks! What if i wanted to say if s[i][j] was greater than 82 characters given? how would i print out the 82nd character with an error?

Comment: What if I wanted to print out the 82nd character?

Comment: If count == 82, then store the input in a different variable and print it using cout where you print your error message.

Comment: 9x9==81 - how is it possible to get 82?